# How to use drush to give permissions to user

Tags: drupal-7

Is there is any Drush Command for Drupal 7 to give all permissions to a newly created role?

Comment: The only time you should have a role with ALL permissions is the Administrator/SuperUser (User ID 1, created when installing Drupal), which Drupal already has. I find myself constantly resetting admin permissions on dev sites, so the question is still very relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, if you don't have an admin role, then you can do this: 
create a role with drush:

```html
 drush role-create 'my role'
```

Then, you can add all permissions to the created rol:

```html
drush eval "user_role_grant_permissions(user_role_load_by_name('my role')->rid, array_keys(user_permission_get_modules()));"
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I hope this help you:

1. You shouldn't grant all permissions to an anonymus role, because it is not even login into the Drupal site. And it could be extremly dangerious.
2. You should check your drush version because the commands are differents.
3. Suppose you are using Drush 7.x and Drupal 7.x. Could you try this:

   - Create a new user (not role) and grant the Admin permissions to it. Because you don't need a new role, you already have all permissions granted on the Drupal Admin User. To do this:

check all existing roles:

```html
drush role-list
```

```html
drush user-add-role "administrator role" --name="new user"
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, But what if admin role is not present in the site and I have to create this role by using drush and give admin role all the permissions.